# how to update a session variable in after the reload of every page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm setting up a sidebar which has been included on every page of the web site and this sidebar contain a span tag which need to be updated on every reload of the page
i created a session variable in the main Controller and this work just for the first time after the Auth

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use App\Valeur;
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        session(['values' => Valeur::where('etat', 1)->count()]);
    }
}
```

**The result now **
after login i get the expected result but if i made a change in the Database the value of the session variable wont changes

Comment: What do you mean by it works just the first time? What is the expected result and what is the result that you now get?

Comment: after login i get the expected result but if i made a change in the Database the value of the session variable wont changes

Comment: Check if the controller that you are using for the next request extends your Controller class and also if you override the constructor make sure that you call `parent::__construct();` from the child controller.

Comment: yes every controller extend of the The main one i will check the View Composers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers) that allows you to retrieve the data for your views, whenever they are going do be rendered.